# auto install android app after update

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've done some research on the internet, but I couldn't find a clear answer to my question. My question is: when an app is updating itself (I've got a properly working auto-updater) it keeps asking for permission, when it comes to the installing process. Is there anyway to avoid this. Ofcourse the first time someone is installing my app on his android phone the app will ask for some permissions. But when the app has been updated it shouldn't ask for permission and just install and update automatically. Just a note the app is meant to run on devices which are running Android between version 2.3.3 and 4.0.3. And the app won't become available on the android market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, no, you cannot avoid this.  There is no guarantee that an update will automatically require the same permissions as the previous version - and the user is always asked for confirmation.

I had to deal with this in my app (not available through Market, only for a private company with their own server to download the updates from).  The way I presented it, was by writing these details in the user's manual and explaining to the client that it's actually better this way, because the users will see that the update is being applied.